# alignment of controlls in table layout

Tags: xml

i had put table layout on the screen.and i had placed a button on the 6th raw.i want to change the position of button to center.but when i am giving margin left property all the controlls which i had placed in the 2nd column goes towards right.i just want to place the button in center without changing other controlls position.how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this in android..
if so then use following attribute in your xml for button.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that talks about positioning with in table layout hope it helps [TableLayout Cell Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762328/tablelayout-cell-positioning)